# How to generate table for linear mixed model with gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary, lmertest

I would like to reproduce linear mixed models tables with `gtsummary`. This is the dataset I am working on

```
dput(head(dt, 300))
structure(list(A = c("51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", "51", 
"51", "51", "51", "51", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "52", 
"52", "52", "52", "52", "52", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", 
"53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "53", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", 
"54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "54", "55", "55", "55", "55", 
"55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", 
"55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", "55", 
"55", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", 
"56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "56", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
"57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", 
"58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "58", "59", "59", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", "59", 
"59", "59", "59", "59", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", 
"60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60", "60"), B = c("1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), C = c(84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 
84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 84.5, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 
62, 62, 62, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 
88, 88, 88, 88, 88, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 
67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 67.5, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 76, 76, 
76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 
76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 114, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114), D = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "L", "M", "N", 
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A1", "B1", 
"C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "J1", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", 
"R", "S", "U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", 
"K1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "J1", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "J", "K", "I", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", 
"W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "K1", "F1", 
"G1", "H1", "J1", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", 
"K", "I", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "W", "X", 
"Y", "Z", "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "K1", "F1", "G1", "H1", 
"J1", "A", "C", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "L", "M", "N", 
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A1", "D1", "E1", 
"F1", "G1", "H1", "J1", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
"J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "W", "X", 
"Y", "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "J1", "A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "L", "M", "N", 
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A1", "B1", 
"C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "J1", "A", "B", "C", "E", 
"F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "I", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", 
"U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", 
"G1", "H1", "J1", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", 
"I", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "U", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A1", 
"C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "J1", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E", "F", "H", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "Z", "A1"), E = c(53.5486131719382, 
52.0658832701111, 51.1252703023116, 59.6739545998032, 85.865976725962, 
113.631908740832, 63.1049775640581, 54.4456826404504, 93.5395932868018, 
93.995437783387, 84.3354719738765, 63.4595744313194, 78.9841448658563, 
80.0955418627145, 57.3693357479924, 63.8069855423248, 54.5435047121041, 
54.4359096471545, 104.207884372387, 60.6889459499874, 76.1778733075911, 
69.0583401518195, 104.47253354457, 83.7416789866701, 50.2210260529369, 
80.6275644735832, 61.198042471331, 83.3120233171705, 55.2494834957416, 
73.3166134328764, 54.1755327745905, 101.902052850692, 51.7545000131658, 
62.1777969600058, 68.1653724448048, 55.1729911875874, 60.8386538371058, 
70.0968994187555, 78.942019990113, 59.775608067045, 67.0071207629859, 
84.7558493290474, 59.9827945641954, 66.5101252750979, 90.5019717484792, 
64.9092937722916, 58.3571820997381, 66.6329432096269, 67.1205696362189, 
50.6509772755951, 50.6250541888198, 51.3032509054271, 54.5634240777667, 
100.737462226385, 60.3790294243842, 68.3600912175845, 73.7351241074605, 
50.0872462865671, 50.795767069448, 70.8001111843104, 79.5524955072498, 
50.260631010864, 73.9586203858578, 55.9975862773843, 60.0923749090369, 
88.4356678154069, 61.3205867721683, 51.9208379138623, 77.7114105505713, 
51.1320936704931, 97.5576527975265, 109.408798916546, 97.5582215974771, 
62.3086020090593, 57.8304273171539, 86.4260724801027, 50.6136060462806, 
159.226033089812, 142.527435748128, 68.2509910677053, 50.7585563161078, 
72.5319013227746, 66.3728176444309, 51.3970723729174, 50.7052373649285, 
55.8340531142269, 77.722629180697, 77.1731558747748, 64.2394186691872, 
189.095920893828, 60.615727186107, 50.3645135141208, 55.9942816672048, 
128.159899427594, 52.0700161057344, 50.6764380248669, 66.5915700948859, 
52.293288405534, 50.8597241625586, 56.0309438799112, 65.6639233566106, 
53.2984048049127, 54.4032755860799, 54.5345061904833, 87.3398149095851, 
70.0394162153045, 62.5193493531448, 50.5776432558593, 61.3488842907225, 
54.3323955416404, 68.8961149578927, 72.2724562848431, 76.9210030237276, 
50.981156113135, 50.9657184258452, 58.142600273058, 62.5910834427581, 
52.1073411367228, 50.6432911385476, 103.558080309759, 81.233576570001, 
55.9546368219274, 58.9731261750758, 65.193324003293, 73.6731770381325, 
50.9849437764464, 68.252760924268, 77.5045817920251, 57.9762684219772, 
51.0383669946158, 80.0240979940811, 53.20028505691, 57.02354463002, 
55.7567157271443, 56.0506846957972, 80.4283499174123, 55.7842328037292, 
207.997342234812, 51.6921739529286, 57.3491380912525, 90.5056460230801, 
72.6707680779293, 72.8711020235701, 114.977472897774, 53.932054643335, 
53.6158517524058, 81.5473592217656, 79.9567024686436, 63.3500072523791, 
50.5485207695456, 118.822052950273, 101.271446713148, 61.2166167463886, 
64.0107863032943, 66.6487762165541, 58.8583604808201, 64.3599615688179, 
79.9317242811825, 127.161491565041, 76.3743045499247, 120.486969772759, 
67.4582106949668, 52.2450907798009, 119.762572667194, 50.4877114728201, 
82.7574060383183, 96.4140642808373, 108.389200406038, 54.1839718991094, 
58.5138428864389, 131.008826055881, 125.154978277626, 132.98212853187, 
98.929007653993, 68.8806138378277, 59.8788185288713, 56.976956121695, 
50.9102162899625, 51.2726148809701, 198.15146866854, 117.580941983352, 
201.78668948985, 103.854766901191, 159.690331183389, 54.9661582983925, 
194.1059243319, 67.2079451571218, 111.170233038542, 82.1453983419786, 
53.4915551572879, 54.3929611700716, 131.956661489323, 65.1562983240275, 
62.0289313492167, 162.4013400668, 53.879472459576, 159.287884346134, 
57.6989146237285, 52.1184249234992, 56.3289893502059, 53.235865231291, 
81.4312256692937, 79.1786714635215, 111.473904766285, 56.4795708235795, 
55.8204724082951, 57.8464980301213, 53.9811120574278, 59.8141814126068, 
55.1338340280094, 51.2196605317086, 84.1339094964576, 87.2396533788401, 
72.9237013420686, 118.76035795556, 70.9057425870373, 58.9326035381529, 
53.716759573972, 87.6656537129987, 52.7109830793293, 67.6138256264123, 
78.4068987953149, 61.8307880411051, 60.8013473936248, 59.4060994383861, 
98.085608459632, 64.5803707894519, 177.46836973785, 54.8477234996859, 
81.8170015518669, 69.2043125654496, 55.7846278423678, 57.1220876444381, 
55.8905809420105, 54.1240432686922, 153.948238453985, 57.921133450344, 
53.0666207122496, 62.0165981264953, 66.2163973372594, 50.3211074843001, 
50.4421905328129, 96.6862483702221, 165.023892857049, 55.3657894204705, 
61.8236534116221, 145.086461239493, 69.9904449190297, 50.2193262019902, 
112.998708003981, 77.4625319190458, 61.71826548918, 53.1582614429681, 
55.9027809250359, 64.7531484148432, 83.63819468709, 91.0574781582018, 
53.1836963432468, 67.5673750775146, 51.3066517681853, 123.181235932417, 
62.3288352087814, 78.6417479791861, 60.2225325746383, 52.7474995165124, 
166.645115814437, 102.414406703632, 76.1537411117896, 84.163010557389, 
53.3394167031625, 57.5540925685454, 54.8229784073972, 52.0681640127194, 
137.667634492671, 144.556542883844, 77.5384791431714, 58.8787603447788, 
61.0540530917981, 54.5532762632947, 62.1100731411146, 55.5283650723314, 
75.9959185450757, 52.3378671680705, 50.9931045174822, 52.2793494215867, 
56.2793169338571, 70.6715821731965, 97.1724466705225, 58.9404344307155, 
69.6992530973357, 70.9345181855089, 82.1063878264692, 162.422136003165, 
173.873478085856, 68.3646841369622, 56.923573242475, 103.313569709538, 
65.822202907022, 116.656650145337, 58.5151713891827)), row.names = c(NA, 
-300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and here as follows there is the code that I used that returns to me this code.

```
library(flextable)
library(gtsummary)
library(lmerTest)

dt %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = D, 
    ~ lmerTest::lmer(E ~ C*B + (1|A), data = .x) %>%
      tbl_regression(),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack"
  ) %>%
  modify_column_unhide(c(std.error, statistic)) %>%
  as_flex_table()
```

However it returns the following error and I cannot realize either a solution or an an alternative to generate this table.

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `tbl = switch(...)`.
Caused by error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: A)
```

Is there anyone that can help?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: [lmer error: grouping factor must be < number of observations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713228/lmer-error-grouping-factor-must-be-number-of-observations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to fit these models even though the random effect is confounded with the residual variance term (that's what the error is trying to tell you) you can override the check using `lmerControl()` as shown below.

Another alternative would be to use `glmmTMB(..., dispformula = ~0)` to force the residual variance to zero (although you would have to give up Satterthwaite/Kenward-Roger finite-size corrections).

```r
dt %>%
  dplyr::filter(D != "K1") %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = D, 
    ~ lmerTest::lmer(E ~ C*B + (1|A), data = .x,
                     control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev="ignore",
                                           check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore",
                                           )) %>%
      tbl_regression(),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack"
  ) %>%
  modify_column_unhide(c(std.error, statistic)) %>%
  as_flex_table()
```

I tried to get `gtsummary` to work with `lme` (which completely ignores the confounding/non-identifiability), but it was a little too much work ...

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually I found out that lme() cannot be used in gtsummary, as far as I understood (but probably this is my bad). Anyway I have used lme() differently in flextable but by using the D as grouping variable. Do you think that model may somehow suffer, since it was fitted with lme() instead that lmer()?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your issue is gtsummary related. The error message appears to be coming from the model estimation portion. I tried to build the models in each subgroup and got the same error.

```r
library(flextable)
library(gtsummary)
library(lmerTest)

dt |> 
  tidyr::nest(data = -D) |> 
  dplyr::rowwise() |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    mod = lmerTest::lmer(E ~ C*B + (1|A), data = data) |> list()
  )
#> Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `mod = list(lmerTest::lmer(E ~ C * B + (1 | A), data = data))`.
#> ℹ In row 1.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: A)
#> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Actually I can fit the model with lme() from nlme package, by using the same syntax, but I do not how to manipulator the code to get the table with lme(). So Il used the the lmer() function and strangely It does not work. Would you please recommend another solution?

Comment: I don't think nlme package is supported? It doesn't return the modeling object with the parts we need to create the table robustly. Honestly, if the more popular package doesn't converge but nlme does, I would first be concerned about the robustness of your model. Then I would turn my focus to summarizing the model

Comment: So in the case to use lme instead of lmer, is that even possible to get a nice table segragated for D variable?